# Why does the command fire twice?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that queues you into a party finder. When the number of queues reaches 2, it resets to 0. I have 2 commands, one for the first person, another for the second to record their names. However, when I get it to 2, it goes to queue = 0 and also fires the command when queue = 0, making it fire twice.

How can I fix this?

```
import discord
import os
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

@client.event
async def on_message(message): #Defines Message
  
  #If You Queue, And Role Requirement to Do So
  if message.content.startswith('-queue duos'): 
    global queue
    if queue == 1:
      role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)

      if role in message.author.roles:

        print('you have queued')
      
        global author2
        author2 = message.author
        print(author2)

        #Adds Role Duos
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830219965549510656) 
        await message.author.add_roles(role) 

        #Removes Role NoQueue
        role4 = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)
        await message.author.remove_roles(role4)
      
        #Gives Message
        await message.channel.send('you have joined the duos queue sit tight!')

        
        queue += 1
        await message.channel.send(queue)

        if queue == 2:
          queue = 0
          print('SUCCESS')

    if queue == 0:
      role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)

      if role in message.author.roles:

        print('you have queued')
      
        global author
        author = message.author
        print(author)

        #Adds Role Duos
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830219965549510656) 
        await message.author.add_roles(role) 

        #Removes Role NoQueue
        role4 = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)
        await message.author.remove_roles(role4)
      
        #Gives Message
        await message.channel.send('you have joined the duos queue sit tight!')
          
        queue += 1
        
        await message.channel.send(queue)

    #Is They Already Queued and Have Duos Role  
    else:
      await message.channel.send('You Already Queued!')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the `queue` variable and then checking it, which will result in it executing twice, a simple way to fix this is to only use `if` on the first check on the queue, and use `elif` on the others, IE:

```py
queue = 1
if queue == 1:
    #Do Something
    queue = 0
elif queue == 0:
    #Do Something else
    queue = 2
elif queue == 2:
    #Do Something else
    queue = 1
```

The example code above only executes the first `if` statement, since `elif` is only executed if the `if` statement it is linked to was not executed.